# f(f(x)) computable but f(f(f(x))) not computable

Tags: computability-theory

Like the title says, I am looking for a function f from N to N such that f(f(x)) is computable but f(f(f(x))) is not. I think it should exist, because i dont see how knowing how to calculate f(f(x)) would help you calculate f(f(f(x)), but I haven't been able to create a counterexample.

I came up with this question after solving a much easier one, finding a not computable function f(x) such that f(f(x)) is computable. One possible solution is using the fact that you can codify a pair of numbers as a single number, and then define f(x,y) = (HALT y, 0). Then, f(x) is not computable because it codifies HALT, but f(f(x)) = (0,0) so is certainly computable.

However, that previous solution relies on deleting the uncomputable information by the second iteration, and something like that wouldn't solve my new problem because f(f(f(x))) would be computable.

Comment: Are there functions $f$ that are not computable such that $f\circ f=\mathrm{id}$?

Comment: That was exactly the counterexample that I sought to create, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: Some googling turns up slide 18 here: https://www.frontiersinai.com/turingfiles/March/GillesDowek1.pdf   Take an undecidable set $U$ (say, encoding the halting problem), and swap $2n$ and $2n+1$ if $n \in U$, and keep them the same if $n \notin U$

Comment: Thank you, that settles it. I didn't realize it was so simple, i keep trying to make an involution that codified the busy beaver.

Comment: Extending this question, is there a characterization of the sets $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that there exist a function $f$ with $f^m$ computable if and only if $m \in S$? Kevin Casto's comment shows that $S = 2\mathbb{N}$ is possible.

Comment: @Mark: By using an $k$-cycle instead of swapping two adjacent values, also $S=k\mathbb{N}$ is possible for every positive $k$... i.e., map $kn \to kn+1 \to .. kn+k-1 \to kn$. On the other hand, if $f^m$ is computable then surely also $f^{2m}$, $f^{3m}$ etc., thus any such $S$ must be a union of sets of the form $k\mathbb{N}$. Not sure how to bridge the remaining gap, though.

Comment: More generally, if $f^a$ and $f^b$ is computable, then $f^{a+b}$ is computable, since we can compute $f^b(x)$ and then apply the computable function $f^a$. So any set $S$ is the analogue of an ideal in the semigroup $\mathbb{N}$.